# Show that if $f=g$ $\ \lambda \ a.e.$ , then $f=g$.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f, g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Let $E = \{x\in \mathbb{R} \ |\ f(x) = g(x)\}$ and let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure. Show that if $f=g$ $\ \lambda \ a.e.$ , then $f=g$.

#### My Proof (Is this correct?)

Suppose $f\neq g$. We know that the set $E$ is closed, since $f$ and $g$ are continuous. Hence $\mathbb{R} - E$ is open and $\lambda(\mathbb{R} - E)>0$, which is a contradiction. Hence $f=g$.

#### Professors Proof

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary. Since $\lambda (\mathbb{R} - E) = 0$, $E$ must be dense in $\mathbb{R}$ (WHY?). Hence $\exists$ a sequence $x_1, x_2, ... \to x$ in $E$. By continuity, we have:
$$f(x) = \lim f(x_k) = \lim g(x_k) = g(x).$$
Hence $f=g$.

I understand the proof but can't convince myself of why $E$ is dense.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If $E$ is not dense there would be an open interval contained in $\mathbb R \setminus E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E$ isn't dense, we have $E \subset \overline{E} \subsetneq \mathbb{R}$. Then $\mathbb{R} \setminus \overline{E}$ is open and nonempty and therefore contains an open interval, which then is also in $\mathbb{R} \setminus E$.

Comment: Also I think your proof is correct.